# How to know when ios local notification is triggered?

Tags: swift

Please tell me how can I know when local notification is trigger in Swift 4? I have tried everything it seem not working.

Comment: Have u checked this link https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/ios-10-local-notifications-using-swift-3/

Comment: what do you mean by _everything_? can you elaborate that?

Answer (score 0):

**You can create local notification as**

```
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 5, repeats: true)
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent.init()
    content.title = "Danger Will Robinson"
    content.subtitle = "Something This Way Comes"
    content.body = "I need to tell you something, but first read this."

    let notification = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notification.add(UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "notification", content: content, trigger: trigger), withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

**When notification is triggered in background and user taps the notification.**

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Swift.Void)
```

**When notification is triggered and app is in foreground.**

```
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void)
```

You must confirm UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to get the triggers.

So best approach is you initialise local notification in appDelegate.

Comment: doesn't meet with what I want.